# Set cookie on response in lumen 5.6

Tags: lumen

Actually I want to set header like this

```
response()->json($data)->header('Set-Cookie','strCookie1',false)->header('Set-Cookie','strCookie2',false)->send();
```

But the `Set-Cookie` not shown in the header.
Is there any way to set the cookie in Lumen 5.6

I saw the `withCookie(cookie())` but not sure how to use. The `cookie()` in Lumen is not defined.

Note: I need 2 `set-cookie` at the same time, and the `strCookie1` is already the full long string of the cookie value.
(Like this: `TOKEN=abcxyz; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 24 Mar 2019 03:40:11 GMT; Max`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation [here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#basic-responses):

> However, for most routes and controller actions, you will be returning a full  `Illuminate\Http\Response` instance. Returning a full `Response` instance allows you to customize the response's HTTP status code and headers. A Response instance inherits from the  `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class, providing a variety of methods for building HTTP responses:

You can find the appropriate method to set cookie [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Response.html#method_withCookie). The argument is either string or a [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie`](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html) instance. If you see the code inside it ([here's the link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/ResponseTrait.php#L108)), the `string` argument only accepted when the
`cookie` function is defined. In this case, it's not defined. So this method only leaves you one option:

**To supply the first argument with an instance of 
`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie`**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

$response
    ->withCookie(
        new Cookie($name, $value, $expire)
    );
```

Comment: Nice thanks. So for the 'strCookie1' string, I need split it out and pass to the parameters.

Comment: Yep, more less `$response->withCookie(new Cookie('strCookie1', false));`