# How to set a cookie on response in Laravel Lumen 8

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, lumen

I'm currently building a REST API with Laravel Lumen 8. I want to set a cookie if the user logged in successfully. I saw that in the Lumen 5.1 docs there was a section that showed how to send a cookie with the response (https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses). But in the documentation for version 8 this section is missing. I also looked into the Laravel 8 docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses) and tried the following things in my routes/web.php file:

**Attempt 1**

```php
$router->get('/test', function () {
    return response('Hello World')->cookie(
        'name', 'value', 60
    );
});
```

But then I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::setCookie() must
> be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie, string
> given

**Attempt 2**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

$router->get('/test', function () {
    Cookie::queue('name', 'value', 60);
    return response('Hello World');
});
```

> Error message: Target class [cookie] does not exist.

**Attempt 3**

```php
$router->get('/test', function () {
    $cookie = cookie('name', 'value', 60);
    return response('Hello World')->cookie($cookie);
});
```

Error message: Call to undefined function cookie()

**Attempt 4**

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
$router->get('/test', function () {
    return response(null)->withCookie(new Cookie('name', 'value'));
});
```

This solution works, but if i set the third parameter like this `new Cookie('name', 'value', 60)`, I don't get an error message but the cookie doesn't get set anymore.
And I'm also a bit sceptical because I never saw this in any official docs but only in this stack overflow question: [Set cookie on response in lumen 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819773/set-cookie-on-response-in-lumen-5-6).

These weren't the only things I tried but nothing worked so far. Setting a cookie should be such an easy thing but I just can't achieve it. I'm pretty new to Laravel/Lumen, has it something to do with the new Version 8? Or what else am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you import this class `Illuminate\Http\Response` for first atempt

Comment: Yes, I added `use Illuminate\Http\Response;`

Comment: Yii2 is better for WebDev 2021.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, this is not pretty but it fixed it for me.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
...
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->setCookie(Cookie::create('foo', 'bar'));
$response->send(); // <- this guy
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the [jwt-auth library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) by Sean Tymon for JSON Web Token Authentication, this Thread may help you: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1594#issuecomment-395575980

Cited from the thread:

> The root of the culprit I guess is that Lumen by design no longer does
> cookies which I find a bit of a flaw in the light of all the blogs and
> OWASP suggestions of not storing a JWT in localstorage but rather in a
> httponly cookie to prevent XSS and deal with CSRF accordingly. So, the
> jwt-auth doesn't include the cookie parser with the
> LumenServiceProvider which is what you register in app.php as a
> service provider:

```
$app->register(Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LumenServiceProvider::class);
```

> So when you add

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Parser\Cookies;
to the top of jwt-auth\src\Providers\LumenServiceProvider.php
```

> and add

```
new Cookies($this->config('decrypt_cookies'))
```

> into the array at the very end of the file

```
$this->app['tymon.jwt.parser']->setChain([<br>
            new AuthHeaders,
            new QueryString,
            new InputSource,
            new LumenRouteParams,
            new Cookies($this->config('decrypt_cookies')),
        ]);
```

> then you should be able use the cookie authentication in Lumen as
> well.